# syntaxError: (unicode) error 'utf-8' codes can't decode byte 0xfb in position 0: invalid start byte

Tags: python, unicode, print

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Доброго времени суток.
Пытаюсь написать в команде print('любой текст с русскими буквами') и собственно ничего не получается. Пишу на английском языке текст, все работает.
Не подскажете как исправить?

Язык - Python

Comment: Мы должны сами догадаться, какой язык программирования используется?

Comment: а язык то какой? питон?

Comment: Прошу прощения за такое упущение :D
Да, Питон

Comment: убедитесь, что Visual Studio сохраняет исходный файл (`.py`), используя utf-8 кодировку, а не cp1251 или cp866.

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас python2, то у вас все строки по умолчанию - байтовые. Следовательно при попытке вывести получаете ошибку.

Чтобы байтовую строку перевести в unicode строку нужно либо добавить явное преобразование типов (напр. print(unicode(my_string)) ), либо, если строка задаётся прямо в файле или интерпретаторе, указать python'у, что это юникод-строка добавив символ 'u' перед открывающей кавычкой, например, print(u'строка')

Для решения этой проблемы в последних версиях python 2 (в частности в 2.7) произведено портирование юникодовых строк из python 3. Чтобы все строки в файле .py стали юникодовыми необходимо добавить вверху файла

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

Если вы пытаетесь сделать это в файле .py, то необходимо указать первой строкой кодировку этого файла, так как python2 считает это ascii файлом. Это можно сделать добавив строку

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

в начало файла.

В python 3 все строки unicode и таких проблем обычно не возникает.

**Обновлено 2**

Исправьте файл, чтобы он выглядел так

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print('ку-ку')
```

**Обновлено 3**

coding: utf-8 лишь говорит python, что содержимое файла следует интерпретировать как utf-8. Проверьте в вашем редакторе действительно ли это так. Мне кажется если решение выше не поможет, то проблема именно в этом - ваш редактор сохраняет в windows-1251 кодировке. Надо найти где это настраивается и изменить

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41938/discussion-on-answer-by-feroxtl-syntaxerror-unicode-error-utf-8-codes-cant).

Comment: Попробуйте STDOUT_CODING = sys.stdout.encoding.  далее print(text.encode(STDOUT_CODING,'replace').decode(STDOUT_CODING)